# how to delete all the line items from the file after the first one

Tags: linq

I need to delete all the line items `<LineItem>` from the file which does not suffice with this requirements:
elements in Line Item : `<LineItemNumber V="00000000000000000010" />` and `<PurchaseOrderNumber V="0100230946|00010" />` have to be matched, another words in integer Line Item Number would be 10 and Purchase order number after pipe line | would be 10. we need to have only one those line Items which are matching this requirement. Sorry, i'm really bad at describing.

```
<Transmission>
  <InterchangeUsageIndicator V="T" />
  <Groups>
    <Group>
      <GroupSenderID V="CCC" />
      <TotalNumberOfShipmentsInGroup V="000005" />
      <Documents>
        <Document>
          <DocumentHeader>
            <InvoiceChargeType V="T" />
            <DocumentType V="ORDER" />
            <DocumentProcessingCode C="00" />
            <BOLNumber V="BOL2309460180582136" />
            <AlternateQuantities>
              <AlternateQuantity Quantity="12.0" UOM="PK" UOMType="SQ" Characteristic="" />
            </AlternateQuantities>
            <Buyer Name="" Q="ZP" ID="COUSPO001">
              <AlternateIDs />
            </Buyer>
            <Seller Name="" Q="2" ID="CNTR">
              <AlternateIDs />
            </Seller>
            <Parties>
              <Party PartyType="SF">
                <Name V="SHA" />
                <LocationID Q="" ID="" />
                <AlternateLocationIDs>
                  <LocationID Q="" ID="SHA" />
                </AlternateLocationIDs>
                <City V="Shanghai" />
                <Country V="CN" />
                <LocationPurpose V="" />
              </Party>
              <Party PartyType="ST">
                <Name V="LEB" />
                <LocationID Q="" ID="" />
                <AlternateLocationIDs>
                  <LocationID Q="" ID="LEB" />
                </AlternateLocationIDs>
                <City V="Lebanon" />
                <Country V="TN" />
                <LocationPurpose V="" />
              </Party>
              <Party PartyType="VN">
                <Name V="YANGZHOU BAOYI SHOES" />
                <LocationID Q="" ID="4100000423" />
                <AlternateLocationIDs />
                <City V="JIANGSU" />
                <Country V="CN" />
                <LocationPurpose V="" />
              </Party>
            </Parties>
            <DateReferences>
              <DR Type="D" Q="ETA" Date="2019-12-19" />
              <DR Type="D" Q="EST" Date="2019-11-28" />
            </DateReferences>
            <ReservedReferences>
              <RR Type="R" Q="K6" V="86|SEAL230946" />
              <RR Type="R" Q="V3" V="VYG230946|BKG230946" />
            </ReservedReferences>
          </DocumentHeader>
          <Vessel VesselName="VSL230946" VesselNumber="" VesselCountryOfRegistration="" VesselRegistrationNumber="" />
          <Equipments>
            <Equipment Initial="CNTR" Number="230946" Length="0" Type="" TotalContainerVolume="52.06" />
          </Equipments>
          <LineItems>
            <LineItem>
              <LineItemNumber V="00000000000000000010" />
              <LineItemType C="LI" />
              <TransportationServiceCode Code="" />
              <PurchaseOrderNumber V="0100230946|00010" />
              <AdditionalReferenceNumber V="" />
              <DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
                <CommodityCode Q="" C="M9160" />
                <BuyerProductID V="" />
              </DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
              <BilledRatedAsQuantity V="0.0" UOM="PA" />
              <LadingQuantity V="0.0" UOM="PA" />
              <LineItemTotalAmount V="0.0" />
              <LineItemWeight V="0.00" />
              <LineItemVolume V="0.00" />
            </LineItem>
            <LineItem>
              <LineItemNumber V="00000000000000900001" /> //this one would not work,because it is 900001
              <LineItemType C="LI" />
              <LineItemSubType C="SCH" />
              <TransportationServiceCode Code="" />
              <PurchaseOrderNumber V="0100230946|00010" />
              <AdditionalReferenceNumber V="" />
              <DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
                <CommodityCode Q="" C="M9160" />
                <BuyerProductID V="" />
              </DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
              <BilledRatedAsQuantity V="24.0" UOM="PA" />
              <LadingQuantity V="24.0" UOM="PA" />
              <LineItemTotalAmount V="0.0" />
              <UserDefinedReferences>
                <UDR Type="U" Q="CR" V="22859470896|001|0001" Description="" />
                <UDR Type="U" Q="S6" V="|3|20" Description="" />
                <UDR Type="U" Q="19" V="M9160|USDS|0001" Description="" />
              </UserDefinedReferences>
              <LineItemWeight V="2959.54" />
              <LineItemVolume V="104.12" />
            </LineItem>
            <LineItem>
              <LineItemNumber V="00000000000000900002" />
              <LineItemType C="LI" />
              <LineItemSubType C="SCH" />
              <TransportationServiceCode Code="" />
              <PurchaseOrderNumber V="0100230946|00010" />
              <AdditionalReferenceNumber V="" />
              <DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
                <CommodityCode Q="" C="M9160" />
                <BuyerProductID V="" />
              </DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
              <BilledRatedAsQuantity V="24.0" UOM="PA" />
              <LadingQuantity V="24.0" UOM="PA" />
              <LineItemTotalAmount V="0.0" />
              <UserDefinedReferences>
                <UDR Type="U" Q="CR" V="22859470902|001|0002" Description="" />
                <UDR Type="U" Q="S6" V="|3.5|20" Description="" />
                <UDR Type="U" Q="19" V="M9160|USDS|0001" Description="" />
              </UserDefinedReferences>
              <LineItemWeight V="2959.54" />
              <LineItemVolume V="104.12" />
            </LineItem>
```

I tried to start on LINQ: this is where I got so far:

```
try {
        var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(msg.Body);
        var xDocument = xDoc.Root.XPathSelectElement("Groups/Group/Documents/Document");
        var xLineItems = xDocument.XPathSelectElements("LineItems/LineItem");
        var poNumbers = xLineItems.Select(e => (string)e.Element("PurchaseOrderNumber").Attribute("V")).Distinct();
        foreach (var poNumber in poNumbers) {
        }
        msg.Body = xDoc.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would like to Delete all `LineItem` where `LineItemNumber!=10` and `PurchaseOrderNumber after the Pipe NOT equals 10`. You could use `Linq` to filter the elements that match the purpose and use the `Remove` method to deletes the selected nodes.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
xDoc.Descendants("LineItem") 
    .Where(x=> Convert.ToInt32(x.Element("LineItemNumber").Attribute("V").Value)!=10 
            && Convert.ToInt32(x.Element("PurchaseOrderNumber").Attribute("V").Value.Split('|')[1])!=10
           ).Remove();
var result = xDoc.ToString();
```